# Facebook access token not active until page is refreshed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

I have a function that checks whether the user is logged in to Facebook or not. It works fine, but after a while (like 10 minutes) of not doing nothing (having the page open but not doing any action in it), if I refresh the page, the token expires and an exception is caught with the message:

```
An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

But if I refresh the page again for the second time, so that the function executes again, then I get a new Access Token and there is no problem. Why is that? Why I am not getting a valid token in the first refresh? And also, why is the token expiring so soon (10 minutes)?

Here is the code of the function that I am talking about:

```
$_FB = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'APP_ID',
    'secret' => 'APP_SECRET',
));

$userFID = $_FB->getUser();

try {
    $user_profile = $_FB->api('/me');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $userFID = 0;
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Does anybody know if I am doing something wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you still dealing with this? Same thing is happening to me.